# how (a!)/(b!) = (b + 1)×(b + 2)×⋯×(a − 1)×a

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

I was solving a problem in which i need to figure out the prime factorization of $\frac{a!}{b!}$ and i did that by computing (a!) and then (b!) by looping ((1 to a) & (1 to b)) and then derived **n** by dividing them ($n = \frac{a!}{b!}$) and then prime factors of n, but it gives me to TLE(Time limit exceeded) so i refered editorial and in editorial they describe an alternate method , they says
**factorization of number $\frac{a!}{b!}$ is this same as factorization of numbers $(b + 1)\times(b + 2)\times \cdots\times (a - 1)\times a$.**

I am unable to figure out how

$\frac{a!}{b!}$  == $(b + 1)\times(b + 2)\times \cdots\times (a - 1)\times a$ ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Can you give us the specific problem you were trying to solve?

Comment: Although there are answers to your question, your question will be closed if you do not add some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32223/what-kind-of-context-is-good-to-add-to-a-contest-math-question?cb=1). The chances are that your question is not unique, and if you don't edit, there is likely a better version of your question out there. For instance, there's one on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h166869p927900) found using Approach0.

Comment: @TobyMak sure but it is coding problem and this equation is part of that question, here is the link to the question https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/546/D

Comment: @TobyMak What more context should i add ? and i haven't found this particular question anywhere, though it may be part of some answer but not particular answer.

Comment: I see. Now add this information to the question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to compute $\frac{a!}{b!}$ in the most computationally efficient way possible. This counts as context as it is the *motivation* for the question (the reason why you are asking). This information is in [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Your question will also be improved by explaining the strategy you used (specifically, the $n = a!/b!$ strategy). Can you write down which factorisation algorithm you tried to use? If you edit, I will be happy to vote for reopening (you need 5 reopen votes for your question to be reopened).

Comment: @TobyMak updated, any other suggestions ?

Comment: What is TLE? You should write the abbreviation in full. Also, please use proper punctuation in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a > b$. Then:

$$\frac{a!}{b!} = \frac{a(a-1)(a-2) \cdots (b+1) \cdot (b)(b-1)(b-2) \cdots (3)(2)(1)}{b(b-1)(b-2) \cdots (3)(2)(1)}$$
$$= \frac{a(a-1)(a-2) \cdots (b+1) \cdot \require{cancel} \cancel{(b)(b-1)(b-2) \cdots (3)(2)(1)}}{\cancel{(b(b-1)(b-2) \cdots (3)(2)(1)}}$$

Do you see how this works?

Comment: Now it's working.

Comment: $a>b$ is required for $a!/b!$ to be factorable

Comment: I have written "assume $a>b$".

Comment: it's easy but i was not able to figure it out :(

Answer (score 2):

"I am unable to figure out how":

- observe that the product is made of consecutive integer factors up to $a$;
- recall that a factorial is a product of consecutive integers;
- see that the product is a subproduct of $a!$;
- understand that the missing factors are precisely those of $b!$;
- conclude.

Observation of the patterns is the key.

Comment: IMO, it is easier to find the general principle for the prime factorization of a number and work out $a,b$ separately, than by simplifying the fraction !

Comment: i just lost in confusion that as  a and b are different so how they are included in one equation but now i can see that, thankyou @Yves Daoust

Answer (score 0):

Expand the factorial!

If $a!/b!$ is factorable at all, it is greater than one, so it follows that $a>b$.

Note that $a!=(a)(a-1)(a-2)\cdots(2)(1)$ can now be faithfully expressed as $a!=(a)(a-1)\cdots(b+1)(b)(b-1)\cdots(2)(1)$

And just divide through.

Hopefully this helps!